# flutter: size of cachednetworkimage in showbottommodal is too small

Tags: flutter, image-size

I am trying to get the `CachedNetworkImage` to a bigger size than the one in the picture. I tried setting and resetting the heights of all the widgets, but I was not able to make it bigger. Can someone please, help.

This is the `ModalBottomSheet` code that includes the image:

```
void showModal(
BuildContext ctx,
String proId,
String name,
String productDescription,
num price,
List<dynamic> img,
num stockCount,
String outId,
String merId
) {

final cartData = Provider.of<CartData>(ctx, listen: false);

showModalBottomSheet<void>(
isScrollControlled: true,
backgroundColor: Colors.white70.withOpacity(0.8),
shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
    topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
    topRight: Radius.circular(30),
  ),
),
context: ctx,
builder: (BuildContext context) {
  return
    // Container(
    // //height: 650,
    // child:
    Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      name,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 22,
                      ),
                      softWrap: true,
                      overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 10),
                Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        //height: 500,
                        // height: MediaQuery
                        //     .of(context)
                        //     .size
                        //     .height,
                        child: CarouselSlider(
                          items: img.map<Widget>((item) =>
                              Container(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3),
                                  child: InkWell(
                                      onTap: () {
                                        Navigator.of(
                                            context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) =>
                                            FullScreenImage(
                                              image: item
                                              //Image.network(item, fit: BoxFit.contain)
                                            )));
                                      },
                                      child: CachedNetworkImage(
                                        imageUrl: "$item",
                                        //height: 500,//MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                                        // width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*.7,
                                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                      )),
                                  )
                          )
                              .toList(),
                          options:  CarouselOptions(
                              enableInfiniteScroll: false,
                              initialPage: 0,
                              autoPlay: true,
                              autoPlayInterval: const Duration(seconds: 4),
                              autoPlayAnimationDuration:
                              const Duration(milliseconds: 800),
                              autoPlayCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
                              enlargeCenterPage: true,
                              viewportFraction: 1
                          ),
                        )
                ),
                      Container(
                        //height: 200,
                        child: SingleChildScrollView(
                          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                          child: Text(
                            productDescription,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                              fontSize: 15,
                            ),
                            softWrap: true,
                            overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
                          ),)),
                    SizedBox(height: 10),
                  ],
                ),
                //flex: 8,
              ),
          Column(
            children: [
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                child:  Text(
                  "₮ ${NumberFormat.decimalPattern().format(price)}",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                    fontSize: 17,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: [
              CartCounter(stockCount),
              Expanded(
                flex: 2,
                child: ElevatedButton.icon(
                  style: ButtonStyle(
                    shape:
                    MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                      RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(13),
                      ),
                    ),
                    backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(
                      color3,
                    ),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    cartData.addToCart(
                      ctx: ctx,
                      productId: proId,
                      price: price,
                      productName: name,
                      countInStock: stockCount,
                      qty: CartCounter.qty,
                      img: img,
                      outletID: outId,
                      merchId: merId
                    );
                  },
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.add_shopping_cart_rounded),
                  label: Text(Languages.of(context)!.addToBasket),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
   // ),
  );
},
);
```

I got so confused. I tried different configurations, at some point I had cropped images with all the empty space around... help appreciated very much! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the options of the carousel there is the aspectRatio property, which controls the size of the items, just change it to a value close to what you like in the example, the default value is 16/9. With this, the area of the carousel item will be larger, you can define custom values for the image, as long as it respects the size of the carousel container.

```
options: CarouselOptions(
aspectRatio: 1,
enableInfiniteScroll: false,
initialPage: 0,
autoPlay: true,
autoPlayInterval: const Duration(seconds: 4),
autoPlayAnimationDuration:
const Duration(milliseconds: 800),
autoPlayCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
enlargeCenterPage: true,
viewportFraction: 1),
```